# how to output to servicebus from httptriggered function

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-functions

**How do we bind output to service bus?**

I've set up an `out` binding inside of my azure function:

```
{
  "queueName": "testqueue",
  "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
  "name": "myQueueItem",
  "type": "serviceBus",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

I've started out with the standard javascript/typescript template for the function:

```
export function run(context: any, req: any): void {
    context.log("TypeScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    context.log(req.query);
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue = req.query; //should bind here

    if (req.query.name || (req.body && req.body.name)) {
        context.res = {
            // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: {
                message: `Hello ${(req.query.name || req.body.name)}`
            }
        };
    } else {
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body"
        };
    }

    context.done();
};
```

I'm getting a response from the function, but nothing is going into service bus.

I've got my app settings for `MyServiceBusConnection` set up, as the portal shows:

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? How do we bind the output to service bus?**

Here's the full `function.json` file:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "queueName": "testqueue",
      "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
      "name": "myQueueItem",
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/HttpTriggerTS/index.js"
}
```

Comment: are you directly creating the function from the portal UI ?

Comment: why the name of your binding (myQueueItem) is different from the way you call it in code (context.bindings.outputSbQueue)?

Comment: @FarrukhNormuradov that was the problem !!!!!! make that the answer

Comment: move the comment to the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the name of your binding (myQueueItem) is different from the way you call it in code (context.bindings.outputSbQueue)?

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows a Service Bus output binding in a function.json file and a JavaScript function that uses the binding. The function uses a timer trigger to send a queue message every 15 seconds.

Here's the binding data in the `function.json` file:

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "schedule": "0/15 * * * * *",
            "name": "myTimer",
            "runsOnStartup": true,
            "type": "timerTrigger",
            "direction": "in"
        },
        {
            "name": "outputSbQueue",
            "type": "serviceBus",
            "queueName": "testqueue",
            "connection": "MyServiceBusConnection",
            "direction": "out"
        }
    ],
    "disabled": false
}
```

and here is the sample JS code

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var message = 'Service Bus queue message created at ' + timeStamp;
    context.log(message);   
    context.bindings.outputSbQueue = message;
```

As pointed out by Farrukh, please ensure you are using the correct name in the binding and in the code.(outputSbQueue )

Hope it helps.